# How to save assets as fbx in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, fbx

I generate model buildings dynamically in Unity3d. After they are generated I have lots of Meshes in the Scene. How do I save it as a .fbx file?

Comment: sry i cant provide a good answer, but try to give this link a look.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-exportFBX.html
Hope it helps, good luck.

Comment: That guide is for exporting FBX INTO Unity3D. @Jorge not helpful.
Here is an incomplete but insightful piece of code that is from the 2009 Google code thingy https://gist.github.com/mstevenson/6159107 via Matt Stevenson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this plugin that may help you:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/37276

If you just need to save your models for further use, however, the simplest way to do it is to save them with Unity own format using `AssetDatabase.CreateAsset` from `UnityEditor` package, like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh, "Assets/mesh.asset");
    }
}
```

Or you can use this free plugin to export OBJ:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15862

Comment: I don`t want use AssetDatabase, because I have many count of meshes and meterials - it takes long time save each assets separate  (somethimes 1 day).

I don`t may use format .obj, because its could not save transform of meshes. I have many gameObjects, that contains the same mesh, but with some transform (move, scale or rotate). If I use obj then its generate for each new transfrom gameobject new mesh - Its very bad, because I generate assetbundles for its (very big size of assetbundles became).